# SVM and logistic regression: steps and selection of predictors

Tags: r, regression, svm

I need help, I am a statistics student and I am doing my final degree project and I am a bit lost, the steps I have taken to make the svm and logistic regression models have been:

- univariate analysis, elimination of nulls, etc...
- Transformation of categorical variables to dummy variables (all the variables in my data are categorical)
- Multivariate analysis: Spearman's correlation for ordinal variables and Pearson's correlations for nominal variables (the dummies). All this to study multicollinearity.
- VIF method on dummy variables
- Regression lassos for the choice of predictors to apply it in SVM models and logistic regression.
- Decision tree on the original variables (without transforming to dummies).

Please, I need to know if all these steps are ok and am I doing this right?